# Removing specific column via powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to remove [Company]:IT Test  column. But no luck.

input CSV file :

```
[Company]:IT Test,[CompanyXYZ]:IT Test12,[CompanyXY]:IT Test222
data11,tst11,user11
data23,tst44,user44
```

my desired output:

```
[CompanyXYZ]:IT Test12,[CompanyXY]:IT Test222
tst11,user11
tst44,user44
```

Script :

```
Import-Csv 'C:\input.csv' -Delimiter "," | Select * -ExcludeProperty '[Company]:IT Test' |
    Export-Csv "c:\output.csv" -Delimiter "," -Encoding UTF8 -notypeinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the source code of `Select-Object` Cmdlet, the value of `ExcludeProperty` is first compiled as a wildcards pattern before performing the matching. See the relevant part of [source code here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/Select-Object.cs#L366).

As per the official [about_Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.3#long-description) docs, powershell supports following set of wildcards.

| Wildcard | Description | Example | Match | No Match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| * | Match zero or more characters a* | aA, ag, | Apple | banana |
| ? | Match one character in that position | ?n | an,in, on | ran |
| [ ] | Match a range of characters | [a-l]ook | book, cook, look | took |
| [ ] | Match specific characters | [bc]ook | book, cook | hook |
| `* | Match any character as a literal (not a wildcard character) | 12`*4 | 12*4 | 1234 |

Since `[ ]` is part of wildcard pattern syntax you need to escape it using ` to literally match with `[]`

```
select * -ExcludeProperty '`[Company`]:IT Test'
```